Cannot use ARB bindless texture extension
I was trying to implement the bindless texture functionality in my Application. I added the ARB extension for bindless texture while generating glad 4.6
But the problem is whenever I call any function related to the bindless texture like glGetTextureHandleARB() the Application breaks and debugger spots the call stack to the ARB function related to bindless texture as the reason for breakdown
When I add the #extension ARB_bindless_texture: enabled on top of the shader it says that this extension is not available.
What does that mean? Is that because my driver doesn’t support that? If it doesn’t support the bindless texture extension, what can I do?
My driver is: Intel (R) 520 HD

Intel 520 HD does not support this extension. Unless you go for software rendering, there is no way to use it on your machine.

Re. "If it doesn’t support the bindless texture extension, what can I do?": what do you want to do?  What are you doing that requires more than the 'basic' 16 or so texture units?  As presented this is really an xy-problem.
